# Websocket port problem because already in use?

Tags: php, html, websocket

Based on the expert recommendation of the IANA, the WebSocket protocol by default uses port 80 for regular WebSocket connections.

How can I make my websocket listen to port 80 when the Apache server is already listening to this port?

I made it works when my WebSocket were using port 12345 but I do not want to open to everyone that port and IANA recommend port 80... but I do not get how to make it works with that port?

#### Idea #1

I have read that for Jabber server that you can use Apache to redirect the call. Here is an example from [this website](http://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/ever-wondered-how-gmailfacebook-chat-works/) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/http-bind/ http://jabber.yourdomain.com:5280/http-bind/ [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Maybe I can do something like that with the websocket... what is your thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The rule, in every OS I know of, is one process, one port. And that makes sense. If you have two processes listening to the same port, then who is to say which one should handle it? You'll have to expose some other port on that machine.

Comment: why the IANA recommend port 80 if they know it gonna be used in a webserver?

Comment: IANA expects that you run a webserver that supports websockets right alongside normal HTTP requests. As far as I know, though, those don't really exist yet, so...

Comment: Check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) on the topic. I specifically noticed the quote, `ordinary TCP connections to ports other than 80 are frequently blocked by administrators`. That would be a very good reason why most people would want to use 80 but why you wouldn't.

Comment: At this moment I want to use a port that won't be blocked too. That's why I am seeking a way to hook the port 80 by a way...

Comment: Well, port 81 is often used as a fallback for 80. You might be able to get through on that one.

Comment: Your rule is invalid for Windows. IIS allows you to share port 80 based on paths

Comment: It's a windows only limitation as far as I know. In Linux you should be able to bind any number of programs to a single port. It's up to the program to ensure that the data it gets is correct.

Comment: Weird because I got this error on a Linux distribution also (production)

Comment: @Mark and @Hasan If this is possible, please link to the documentation which demonstrates it. My experience -- if IIS is using 80, then Apache can't. I know that MySQL won't *let* you run if netstat says that anything is on the same port. I'm pretty sure that this is a fundamental part of the whole TCP architecture.

Comment: What about the suggestion I made (see the edit in the question)?

Comment: That is a great solution. If you put that as an answer I would definitely vote for it (and you may want to mark that as the answer too)

Comment: Alright, I have posted my possible solution. I still need to test it next weekend :)

Answer (score 1):

The websocket protocol uses port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS). What we've done is use port 80 for our webserver and port 443 for the websocket. This prevents the clash but still follows the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Its a fundamental design principle of the sockets library that the port number identifies a single endpoint for a network interface. If Apache or any other program  has port 80 then it belongs to that program and only that program.

Think about it if you were somehow to "share" port 80 with Apache how could I which choose which process to send my message to?

It is possible to have one process listening on one network interface (say Apache using port 80 your Ethernet LAN ) and another process using the same port number on another interface (say Proxy server using port 80 on your Wireless Lan).

Answer (score 0):

I have read that for Jabber server that you can use Apache to redirect the call. Here is an example from [this website](http://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/ever-wondered-how-gmailfacebook-chat-works/) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/http-bind/ http://jabber.yourdomain.com:5280/http-bind/ [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Maybe I can do something like that with the websocket... what is your thought?